# ROWNUM equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, rownum

Is there any function in PostgreSQL which generates sequential series for a column like ROWNUM works in Oracle?

Code:

```
TO_CHAR(ROWNUM) AS "TransactionID"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `row_number() over ()`

Comment: They did write a manual with all (window) functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

Comment: TO_CHAR is Oracle specific. ROWNUM is also Oracle specific. With PG, which is close to the ISO standard SQL, you must write your query as : CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) AS VARCHAR(32)) AS TransactionID (double quote are not required....